# React Native write into file

Tags: react-native

I have following react native app structure (simpilifed)

```
- /MyApp
  - /ios
  - data.json
  - index.ios.js
```

So, i need to access and write into data.json file. To access them, i can  `import Data from './data.json'`.

But how can i write into this file? I seen react-native-fs (https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs), but i can not access the file in my `MyApp` directory.

How do i store files like my `data.json`, so i can write and access them on my iphone?

My `data.json` file contains a bigger list of vocabulary, like

```
{
  "words": [
    {"word": "xxx", "done": false} // and more...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can write into the file by react-native-fs. But the write access file path is depend on your phone platform like ios or android.

```js
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
 // create a path you want to write to
 var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';

// write the file
RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
.then((success) => {
 console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
})
.catch((err) => {
 console.log(err.message);
});
```

This is the way to create new file and write your data. If you want to write data append file you need read the data and create new string write back to the file. Or you modify the Java and Ojb-c code yourself to create a new api to write append.

Comment: I am not sure. It is a year ago.  :)